"Error":"class org.tron.core.services.http.JsonFormat$ParseException : 1:34: INVALID hex String"
Im trying to create a transaction to activate a tron address after creating it. below is my code for creting the address:
        func CreateTRC20Address() (string, *ecdsa.PrivateKey, error) {
    // Generate private key
    privateKey, err := crypto.GenerateKey()
    if err != nil {
        return "", nil, err
    }

    fmt.Println("private key: " + fmt.Sprintf("%v", privateKey))

    // Get public key from private key
    publicKey := privateKey.Public()
    publicKeyECDSA, ok := publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        return "", nil, fmt.Errorf("error casting public key to ECDSA")
    }

    // Step 1: Hash the public key using SHA-256
    publicKeyBytes := crypto.FromECDSAPub(publicKeyECDSA)
    sha256Hash := sha256.New()
    sha256Hash.Write(publicKeyBytes)
    sha256HashedPubKey := sha256Hash.Sum(nil)

    // Step 2: Hash the result using RIPEMD-160
    ripemd160Hash := ripemd160.New()
    ripemd160Hash.Write(sha256HashedPubKey)
    ripemd160HashedPubKey := ripemd160Hash.Sum(nil)

    // Step 3: Add Tron address prefix (0x41) to the RIPEMD-160 hash
    tronAddressBytes := append([]byte{0x41}, ripemd160HashedPubKey...)

    // Step 4: Base58Check encode the Tron address
    checkSum := sha256.Sum256(tronAddressBytes)
    checkSum = sha256.Sum256(checkSum[:])
    tronAddressBytes = append(tronAddressBytes, checkSum[:4]...)

    // Base58 encode the final Tron address
    tronAddress := base58.Encode(tronAddressBytes)

    return tronAddress, privateKey, nil
}

And below is my code for activating the new trc 20 address by sending 0.1trx:
        func CreateTransaction(fromAddress, toAddress string, amount int64) (*Transaction, error) {
    // Convert fromAddress and toAddress to hex
    fromAddressHex, err := ConvertBase58CheckToHex(fromAddress)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid fromAddress: %v", err)
    }

    toAddressHex, err := ConvertBase58CheckToHex(toAddress)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid toAddress: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("fromAddressHex: %s, toAddressHex: %s\n", fromAddressHex, toAddressHex)

    url := fmt.Sprintf("%s/wallet/createtransaction", tronGridBaseURL)
    payload := map[string]interface{}{
        "to_address":    toAddressHex,   // Use hex format
        "owner_address": fromAddressHex, // Use hex format
        "amount":        amount,         // Amount in SUN
    }

    jsonPayload, err := json.Marshal(payload)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal payload: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("CreateTransaction Payload: %s\n", string(jsonPayload))

    resp, err := http.Post(url, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonPayload))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to send create transaction request: %v", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to read response body: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("CreateTransaction Response: %s\n", string(body))

    var transaction Transaction
    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &transaction)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal transaction: %v", err)
    }

    return &transaction, nil
}



But the response I'm getting is as below:
Create Transaction Response: {"Error":"class org.tron.core.services.http.JsonFormat$ParseException : 1:34: INVALID hex String"}.
What might I be doing wrong?
